# Angular 8 calling Rest Api - resource loading takes long time

Tags: angular, performance, browser, postman

I have an API that take 300ms on the browser or postman (HTTP get) 
From angular 8 with httpclient its take 4.5 seconds - most of the time spent on **resource loading** 
The payload is 1K and the body is 330bytes.

Do you have any idea how can I reduce this 4 seconds to the minimum (or close to browser time)

[image: from profiler]

Comment: Hi @Einav. Did you get the solution for this. Even I do have same problem. My inflight requests take more than response time. Even my App is running on Angular 8